# How to keep a window inside your application only?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, window, mdi

I'm writing a WPF application which has a main canvas area, where the user can open a number of windows, drag and drop them and generally move them around the application as he or she pleases.

What I've done so far basically opens windows using the `Show()` method, and I have hidden them from the taskbar.  However, when the main application is minimised, the small windows which have been opened all appear on the desktop.  What I am lookign for is basically a way to keep the windows contained within the application.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but you need to design some infrastructure to replace what MDI used to do ( though often quite badly)

So when you open a new window in your app, add it to a list.
When it closes, take it out
When your main app is minimised, minimise all the windows in the list as well.

You can also trap child window move events and keep them in bounds, take the children with you when the main app moves. Docking, cascade, tiling...

Key bit it to get this list of managed child windows going.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. To be honest that seems a bit too much for functionality which I think should be built in. Aside from the MDI WPF library, am I out of luck? As that is no longer supported

Comment: Well you don't have to implement it all, and one Interface will give you the basics. I can't remember the last time I used built in MDI anyway, Too many hoops to jump through for too much or too little. Didn't even know there used to be MDI in WPF :(

Comment: Well it's not exactly official, it's a library :) So from what I can see it was never officially supported. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called [MDI](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ggaganesh/DevelopingMDIAppplicationsinCSharp11272005225843PM/DevelopingMDIAppplicationsinCSharp.aspx).

[WPF MDI](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. However that library is no longer supported and out of date. I am trying to incorporate the functionality asked in the question.